# How can I use M-x in minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

Say I want to create a file. Then I was asked to enter the name. I want to use the date as the name of file. I want to use `M-x insert date (I define myself)` . How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set (or bind, depending on the context) variable `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil` (e.g. `t`), before the first entry into the minibuffer.

That lets you use actions, such as `M-x` which themselves activate the minibuffer, from within a minibuffer. The second activation takes place in a recursive minibuffer. When it ends (e.g. you hit `RET` after replying to the `M-x` prompt), things continue as they were, with the initial minibuffer still active.

Comment: yuxuan: I recommend also using `(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode 1)` so that you can see when you're in a recursive minibuffer. Without this it can get confusing.

Comment: I second @phils suggestion. See also library [`mbdepth+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/mb-depth%2b.el), which lets you customize the indicator. I also use [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/oneonone.el), which makes it even more obvious when a recursive minibuffer is entered.

Comment: And, don't forget about `M-x abort-recursive-edit` or `C-]` in case you get deep into the recursive edit and want to jump out of the stack.

Comment: @TreyJackson: Yes. Also, `C-g` acts normally in the minibuffer, but at top-level of the minibuffer (i.e., not within some command), it too pops up a recursive level.